# Thucydides + ScalaTest

Tags: scalatest, thucydides

I find the HTML reporter of scalatest pretty basic. I would like something like Thucydides or something else. Does any one has experience or pointer or where to look to find information on how to integrate both of them?

Answer (score 2):

There's rather recent Thucydides equivalent called **[Allure Framework](http://allure.qatools.ru/)**. It has modular structure and can be used with any programming language test framework. Allure already has Scalatest support located **[here](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-scalatest)**. Also take a look at **[demo report](http://teamcity.qatools.ru/repository/download/allure_core_master_release/lastSuccessful/index.html?guest=1)**.